# Different filter to axis X and Y

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

```
Type   Value   Year
1        2      1907
2        3      1907
3        1      1907
4        5      1907
     .  .  .  .
1        24      2021
2        41      2021
3        10      2021
4        81      2021
```

I want to make a scatter plot and with dynamic filtering in a dashboard, choose which type to plot in. But the problem is when filtering I can only make that filter affects both X and Y axis. How to make a filter to X axis and other for Y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create two parameters to ask the user which types to use for the x and y axes, both of type whole number. Show both parameter controls (right click)

The purpose of the parameter is to ask the user a question and record the response. Each parameter can have exactly one value at a time, even though it can have a list or range of possible values.

Then create a boolean calculated field to determine whether a data record should be included, such as `X type = X parameter and Y type = Y parameter` (Its not clear from your problem description what those criteria really are)

Then put your calculated field on the filter shelf, and only include data records where the calc evaluates to True.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Tableau but I have never seen a filter used on anything except selecting which rows to process.

You can accomplish what you describe by having one sheet per X-axis field you want,  normal filtering on the rows ( Y-axis) ,  and a parameter on a dashboard to pick which sheet to display.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_sheet_selector.htm